# show that $\Big||x|^a x-|y|^a y \Big|\leq (a+1)M^a\big|x-y\big| $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $a,\,M>0$ and given $x,y\in[-M,M]$. I want to show the inequality
\begin{align}
\Big||x|^a x-|y|^a y \Big|\leq (a+1)M^a\big|x-y\big|. 
\end{align}

What I did is let $f(t)=|t|^at$, then $f'(t)=\begin{cases}(a+1)t^a,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t\geq0
\\ -(a+1)(-t)^{a-1}t,\ t<0. \end{cases}$

By Lagrange theorem, there exists $z\in(-M,M)$ such that
\begin{align}
\big|f(M)-f(-M)\big|=\big|M+M\big|\big|f'(z)\big|
\end{align}
which implies
\begin{align}
\big|M^aM+M^aM\big|=2(a+1)M\big|z\big|^a.
\end{align}

But how can I keep on from this ? Could anyone give me some guidance ? Thanks.

Comment: there is issues with differentiability at zero. Just break into four cases which is probably reduced to only two due to symmetry (both have same signs or opposite signs).

Comment: @dezdichado: If $a > 0$ then the function is differentiable at zero, with $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: @dezdichado I think my issue may lie in the equality $\big|f(M)-f(-M)\big|=\big|M+M\big|\big|f'(z)\big|$.  I should have use $\big|f(x)-f(y)\big|=\big|x-y\big|\big|f'(z)\big|$ at there

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the derivative as $f'(t) = (a+1)|t|^a$ which is a continuous function of $t$. Then notice that $max_{t\in[-M,M]}|f'(t)| \le (a+1)M^a$, so your claim follows from the fact that every continuously differentiable function is locally Lipschitz (which is implied by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that:

$$\left||x|^a x - |y|^a y\right| \le \left|\int_x^y (a+1)\left|t\right|^{a} \mathrm d t\right|\le (a+1) M^a \left|x-y\right|$$

Comment: without using the integral